# unable to assign QQuickText to QString

Tags: javascript, qml, qstring

I am trying to dynamically create objects in qml-javascript.The function which creates the object is:

```
function createSpriteObjects(xPos,yPos,cnt,imgsrc,jsonObject) {
    var title;
    title = jsonObject.matches[cnt].recipeName;
    var component = Qt.createComponent("FlickItem.qml");
    component.createObject(wall.contentItem, {"color":"white", "x":xPos,"y":yPos,"src":imgsrc,"opacity":1,"title":title});
}
```

The recieving file(FlickItem.qml) has a property string title which is later assigned to the text field of the Text item:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
id: name
opacity: 0
property string title: ""
width:100
height:100
color:"white"

property string src: ""

Image {
   id:recipeimages
   source: src
   width:240
   height:160
}
Text {
   id: title
   anchors.bottom: recipeimages.bottom
   anchors.horizontalCenter: recipeimages.horizontalCenter
   anchors.bottomMargin: 5
   color: "white"
   font.pixelSize: 24
   text:title
}
```

the following error is returned:

> unable to assign QQuickText to QString

Any way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Rectangle {
id: name
//...
property string title: ""  <------ title
//...
}

Text {
   //...
   id: title   <----- title
   //...
   text:title    <---- which title ?!?!?!
}
```

The problem is you have a `property` bound to the *title* identifier, and an `id` bound to the *title* identifier. Based on your output, you are likely trying to assign text from the `id` (and not the `property`).

Changing the `id` of your `Text` component should solve your problem.